# How to change value of a stateful widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter

class SecondScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  int myIndexValue;

SecondScreen(this.myIndexValue);

@override

```
  _SecondScreenState createState() => _SecondScreenState();
}

class _MusicPlayingState extends State<MusicPlaying> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setState({
      widget.myIndexValue = widget.myIndexValue + 1;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(widget.myIndexValue.toString());
  }

}
```

Edit: I FOUND THE ANSWER. After putting print statements everywhere. i found out the build function of a state widget is called frequently. So i put a setstate in a function and put it under the build method.

Comment: Please be more elaborate of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm trying to change widget.myIndexValue to any number.

Comment: @hellobear You can't modify `widget.X` because it is final, you'll have to do it the way I mentioned in answer.

Comment: Wanna turn your edit into a proper answer for everyone else.

Answer (score 0):

```
class SecondScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final int myIndexValue;

  SecondScreen(this.myIndexValue);

  @override
  _SecondScreenState createState() => _SecondScreenState();
}

class _SecondScreenState extends State<SecondScreen> {
  int _myIndexValue;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _myIndexValue = widget.myIndexValue;
    _update();
  }

  void _update() {
    setState(() {
      _myIndexValue = _myIndexValue + 1;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(_myIndexValue.toString());
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work but its understandable. I want to set a state variable to a stateful widget value e.g. var a = widget.a; Also even if i do that and try to access it, it doesn't return anything.